# when using flower to monitor celery workers, how should I know where the worker is deployed?

Tags: python, celery, flower

in flower I found some workers that I don't know where it located, because I need to  update the worker, for the unknown ones, I can remove it from consuming . Is there any way that I can find where the worker was deployed? I guess some other developer start them locally,but how should I know the IP address ?[image]